# How to change mouse to left handed but keep touchpad right handed?

Tags: mouse, touchpad

:D
I just had my pc reformatted and I have a change in my "Mouse" window. It shows something like this now:

[image]

But it used to show something like this:

[image]

In the upper picture, you can only swap the primary and secondary buttons. But doing so, you change BOTH the MOUSE and the TOUCHPAD. Before, I was able to just change the mouse to left handed.

I'd like to only change the mouse to the left handed...

Comment: Install the drivers for your touchpad. If you guve us make and model of your laptop we can post a normal answer.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the quick reply. I wasn't aware this info was needed.
I have a toshiba computer, I have a toshiba sattelite c660, is that what is meant by "model" of the laptop"? And I am running a windows 7 home premium. Thank you again.

Comment: Agrees with LPchip, if your going through the standard windows driver with both input devices the change is going to be to that driver/software item, and effect all the input devices using it. If it will be possible it will only be possible if there is a seperate driver and/or software that your changing the settings for.

Comment: Thanks all for the advices. I installed the driver and it's back to normal now! :D Much thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

I just installed EasyMouse to solve this. http://eithermouse.com/
There was a good review at http://www.commonitman.com/2014/03/use-eithermouse-for-managing-multiple.html

Comment: The first link is broken.

Comment: thanks, although don't know the mechanism, it works!

Answer (score 0):

Yup, after some tinkering, EitherMouse fixed the same for me with Logitech mouse and Dell touchpad. Finally!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1153860)